# iCal errors bypass

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm importing iCal links with calendar availabilities. 
When I try to import an iCal from a specific provider, I get errors. Also when I try to validate it on http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/ there are plenty of errors.

However, when I import it to Google Calendar, it works perfectly fine.

Any tips how to sort this out? Is there a tool to fix iCal errors? or what should I add to my import code to bypass these errors?

Sample link of iCal with errors that works on Google Calendar - Updated link to:
http://www.worldtravelsuites.com/ics/8585.ics

Thanks!

Comment: The link you provided goes to a webpage rather than a calendar, please provide a correct link to your calendar or update your question with the calendar itself.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply.
This is actually also an iCal link. If you import it as is to a google calendar it works. 

Do you think the issue is the link structure? How does google solve it then?

Many thanks!!

Comment: I just tried the URL above with google calendar and the ical validator and neither recognised it as an iCal file.  I also attempted to access the URL sending a Content-Type of application/calendar and no luck there either.  You're going to need to provide more info on how you're providing the calendar, or a sample calendar itself.

Comment: Sorry, it was a wrong link. How about this one - http://www.worldtravelsuites.com/ics/8585.ics

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you aren't formatting the text fields that you are putting in to your calendar.  You have three specific issues in your example calendar:

- You aren't escaping reserved characters
- You aren't sorting out your line breaks
- You aren't folding your lines

All of these are explained in section 3.1 of [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), but to show you where you're going wrong with your specific example:

```
LOCATION:2B - ,  38,  East 23rd Street,  New York,  NY,   - Public Adderass: 23rd St and Park Ave S
```

is not escaping the ',' character and the line is too long.  This should read:

```
LOCATION:2B - \,  38\,  East 23rd Street\,  New York\,  NY\,   - Public Ad
 derass: 23rd St and Park Ave S
```

You need to do similar things with your `DESCRIPTION` and `LOCATION` lines.  Make sure that you remove any linebreaks in your output by changing newlines to `\n` in the text